# Magento REST API, got error while fetching product list

Tags: php, api, rest, magento

I got a problem while gating product in magneto using REST API, First of all I granted all privileges for all accounts in magento / System / WebServices / REST ... Also I created oAuth Consumer. I got with it two variables (key and secret).  I am success for gating oauth_token and oauth_token_secret but when I fetch products got error like

> Invalid auth/bad request (got a 400, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a
>   redirect)
>   oauth_problem=parameter_absent&oauth_parameters_absent=oauth_verifier

my magento version 1.9

Comment: Are you using a custom script as the OAuth client? It's not passing the oauth_verifier parameter along with the API request - this could be either because you forgot to add it into your script OR you haven't actually completed the OAuth authentication process. Have you successfully authorized your consumer application?

Comment: Thank you for reply me Kakshil Shah, Robbie Averil

Comment: I follow this link http://inchoo.net/magento/configure-magento-rest-and-oauth-settings/ for role,    
and
I follow this code from http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html    
Below this heading "Retrieve the list of products for Admin user with OAuth authentication"

But still I could success.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you wrote "First of all I granted all privileges for all accounts in magento / System / WebServices / REST ..." Did you also go to System -> WebServices / REST Attributes and grant all there as well for your chosen role? A 400 error can indicate that the developer forgot the REST Attributes ...